# Setting terms to product attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have managed to add one product attribute on the activation of the plugin. Here is the script.

```
function mycbgenie_add_product_attributes() {

    global $wpdb;

    $insert = $wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies',
        array(
            'attribute_label'   => 'Sold Through',
            'attribute_name'    => 'sold-through',
            'attribute_type'    => 'text',
            'attribute_orderby' => 'order_by',
            'attribute_public'  => 1
        ),
            array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d' )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $insert ) ) {
        throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_cannot_create_product_attribute', $insert->get_error_message(), 400 );
    }

    // Clear transients
    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );

}
```

How can we add some terms to this newly added attribute via script to a particular post?` I mean how can we refer this attribute on below code

```
 update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to first update the terms and then update_post_meta

```
//ensure to replace 123 with a valid product id & 'term name' with a valid term 
wp_set_object_terms( 123, "term name", "pa_sold-through", true);

$product_attributes['pa_sold-through'] = array(
        //Make sure the 'name' is same as you have the attribute
        'name' => htmlspecialchars(stripslashes('Sold Through')),
        'value' => 'term name',  //replace 'term name' with a valid term
        'position' => 1,
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy' => 0
    );

//Add as post meta, ensure to replace 123 with a valid product id
update_post_meta(123, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
```

Comment: I am wondering why this term name does not appear in this screen under the pa: sold-through

Comment: I mean under on this page wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes, it does not show the terms added using above script.

Comment: Is it like that do we need to add terms first using this screen 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes' and refer the term name in the script?

Comment: K.. I found the solution.

Comment: It shows fine at my end, what solution did you apply? deleting transients?

Comment: there is a major problem with this:  it deletes any attributes there may have been before.

Comment: Also, you are approaching the problem wrong:  You do not need to update the post meta when updating/adding terms to a post's attribute.  Basically a post's attribute !== post's meta.  Meta refers to a structural aspect of something, in this case a post, attribute is a property of something, in this case a post.  By that logic, to update/add terms to a post's attribute, you are only updating the wp_terms_relationships table for that post and you DO NOT have to update the post's structural element(meta).  So all you need is wp_set_object_terms, and everything else can be omitted.

Comment: An attribute can be defined by a post's meta, meaning it describes the attribute, but does not give it a value.

Comment: @dave, thank you for the explanation, but I do understand the difference between post meta and post attribute. Your question says you want to _update product attributes_ an not _update product terms_ . In case of WooCommerce product attributes are stored as post meta in wp_postmeta table.

Comment: @AnandShah True, i did address the wrong data in my question, i should've said "how to update attribtue term(s)".  But again in the case of woocommerce's product attributes, we are updating the attribute's term(s), and not the meta value for the product's attribute.  So again, ur solution did not need any updating to the attribute's postmeta, as we wanted to update attribute value, which wp_set_object_terms takes care of.  I even tried it myself, and it worked 100% as expected.

Comment: @dave, just setting the product terms will not make it visible on the front end. If you carefully read the OP's question on this thread, he says _How can we add some terms to this newly added attribute via script to a particular post_ , hence my solution. With just setting the term using `wp_set_object_terms`, one would still need to make use of the backend UI to add it to the product.

Comment: @AnandShah  Actually Anand, your right.  OP did not correctly add an attribute to his woocommerce setup.  He forgot to add it also to wp_postmeta.  So yes your right, I should've read his code and realized he created his own query, which was wrong to begin with.  Great job btw.